# NuGet circular dependency when trying to freshly reinstall packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

so, I wanted to freshly reinstall some Microsoft Servicefabric packages and for that I uninstalled all related packages from my given projects.

When trying to reinstall them, I run into the following issue:

[image]

When trying to install said package, this happens:

[image]

It seems like I have run into some kind of circular dependency here.

My project is currently clean of any any Service Fabric packages, so I am very unclear why Nuget is trying to RESTORE instead of REINSTALLING the packages.

Also, I am quite unsure how I could resolve this right now.

Can someone guide me?

Comment: just a request for the future, please don't take screenshots of text. You can copy/paste it here, making it much, much easier to read. You can prefix it `>` to make it a quote, or use the quote button in the formatting bar, or use the code blocks to preserve new lines. It's really difficult to compare the text of the two messages.

Comment: As for why NuGet is restoring instead of re-installing, I'm going to assume your project uses PackageReference (PR) and not packages.config (PC). WIth PR, NuGet has no concept of install or uninstall. The UI and PMC commands effectively just modify the csproj, do a restore and if it fails, undo the csproj change. This is why .NET Core (only uses PR, never PC) can be developed without Visual Studio. All you need is a text editor and the build tools.

Answer (score 0):

The error message complains about the incompatibility between `Autofac.ServiceFabric 2.2.0 version` and `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 3.4.641 version` package.

Assuming your asp.net core project targets .net core 2.2.0, you can try to add reference to corresponding `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 3.3.644 version` instead of the incompatible `3.4.641` version. Then the Nu1608 and Nu1107 error would go away.

(The [Autofac.ServiceFabric 2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.ServiceFabric/) and [Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 3.3.644](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting/3.3.644) were both released in 4 months ago)